# Mysql selecting some field according to some condition

Tags: php, mysql

```
id  price   tax item    discount
1   500     15  100     0
2   0       15  200     1
3   100     15  500     0
4   0       15  300     0
5   1000    15  88      0
6   0       15  190     1
7   0       15  120     0
```

Select All if both **price** and **discount** or not equal to zero.

[I don't want to select if the value of price and discount both are zero in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0z0w.png)

Not to select only if price and isDiscount both are zero... (only one case)

```
Price   IsDiscount  Select
1       1           Yes
!0      0           yes
0       1           Yes
0       0           no
```

Comment: You don't share what you've tried. You don't even put your question... That's not how things work here. Please follow the community's guidelines.

Comment: Please have a loot at this now

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here, ...but isn't it as simple as

```
SELECT
  id,tax,...
FROM
  tablename
WHERE
   price!=0
   OR discount!=0
```

?

Comment: we are NOT to select all those rows where price and discount both are 0.... if price is 0 and discount is 55. then we want to take this row. Only rows we want to SKIP is where BOTH price=0 and discount=0

Comment: @Vishal Wadhawan yes, and? The query does that, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your simple answer.
the query is as follows :

```
select * from orders WHERE price+discount > 0
```

Comment: Not exactly index-friendly, is it?

Answer (score -1):

select * from from_your_table WHERE price+discount > 0

Comment: Don not select only both price and IsDiscount or zero. Otherwise select all from the table

Answer (score -1):

SELECT
  id,tax,...
FROM
  tablename
WHERE
   (price >0) or (discount>0) or (discount>0 and price>0)

Comment: Ok. Only one case we need not to show is when both are zero . In all other we need to show. Am I right ?

Comment: unless there a negatives prices and discounts, how can price!=0 but not price>0? Same reasoning for discount. I.e. the `or (discount>0 and price>0)` part is superfluous.

Comment: Please check my new code. It's logic is if price and discount both zero then all will be zero (0 or 0 or 0) otherwise it will fulfill other condition. If one of them is not zero then 1 or 0 or 0. If both are not zero 1 or 1 or 1. Please check it once.

Comment: Still the same "problem": `(price >0) or (discount>0) or (discount>0 and price>0)` - the `or (discount>0 and price>0)` adds nothing that hasn't already been covered by the `(price >0) or (discount>0)` part.

Comment: IT was too simple 
Select * from table where(price =0 and dis!=0) or price>0

it worked for me. Thax all of you.